Flutter does not contain . Running lipo -info
I ran my flutter code on a real device and got this error

when I run my applications in simulation I get this error
I found many solutions but did not get proper solutions for this situation

is there anyone who facing these issues or errors in flutter development then guide me, it will be very helpful for me as a beginners level developer in Flutter

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I was getting the same error. I found that, accidentally, I had added x64 (I was testing on the device having the same architecture) in the Excluded Architectures under the Build Settings. I removed it for Any iOS SDK and after that, it started working.
